# Port forwarding in sonic wall

Tags: networking, firewall, portforwarding

I am hosting website in server I had problem with static IP connection
How to do port forwarding in sonic wall
with static ip address

Answer (score 1):

Use the wizard! Works really well and will do all the work for you:

https://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/ext/kb7027-port-utm-how-to-quickly-open-ports-port-forwarding-using-wizards-sonicos-enhanced

If you are doing it manually you will need to do the following:

```
Add the static IP of the server to the Sonicwall as a Network Object.
Create the allow rule to allow traffic from your external interface to the server on only the ports you want.
Create a NAT rule to NAT all traffic from the external interface to the internal networks subnet.
```